# Angular2 load component from external file with javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm following the [angular tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt3.html) on the basics of Angular2, trying to translate it to javascript since it is currently only available for Typescript.

I currently have two files: app.component.js and hero-detail.component.js.
Located in app.component.js i have my AppComponent. From this, I would like to load the component in hero-detail.component.js as a directive.

My current code looks like this, but I can't figure out how to load HeroDetailComponent:

```
app.AppComponent =
ng.core.Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  inputs : ['hero'],
  directives: [HeroDetailComponent],
  template: `<h1>{{title}}</h1>My Heroes<h2></h2>
             <ul class="heroes">
             <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes" 
             [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero"
             (click)="onSelect(hero)">
             <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
             </li>
             </ul>
             <my-hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero"></my-hero-detail>
             `
})
.Class({
  constructor: function() {
  this.title = 'Tour of Heroes'
  this.heroes = HEROES
  this.selectedHero = null
  },
  onSelect(hero) { this.selectedHero = hero; }
});

})(window.app || (window.app = {}));enter code here
```

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html. Official guide is available in typescript, JS and Dart. There is a drop down menu under the heading `5 MIN QUICKSTART`

Comment: @PriyeshKumar The documentation for JS is blank

Comment: @Yasky I don't know where are you looking at, but for me documentation has everything

Comment: @priyeshkumar if you're looking at the quick start documentation, yes, that's complete. However, under the tutorial section, there's only provision for TypeScript and Dart. Regardless, I have answered the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Javascript, all variables are bound to the `app` which is in turn bound to the `window`.

You should define your `HeroDetailComponent` the same way `AppComponent` is defined.

```
(function (app) {
  app.HeroDetailComponent = ng.core.Component({
    selector: 'hero-detail',
    inputs: ['hero'], // <-- this is necessary to receive the "selectedHero"
    template: ` <!-- ... --> `
  }).Class({
    constructor: function () {
    }
  });
})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

Make sure to include the file in your `index.html`

```
<!-- 2. Load our 'modules' -->
<script src='app/hero.js'></script>
<script src='app/hero-detail.component.js'></script>
<script src='app/app.component.js'></script>
<script src='app/main.js'></script>
```

In your `AppComponent`, add the newly created `HeroDetailComponent` like so

```
app.AppComponent = ng.core.Component({
  directives: [app.HeroDetailComponent], <-- // note the dependence on the `app` object
  // ... and other things
}).Class({ /* Class Declaration */ });
```